# How to change color of label edges on diagrammer graphs and avoid overlapping?. R

Tags: r, diagrammer

How can I change the color of the edge's labels on a Diagrammer graph?

I'm able to change the edge color itself but not the text label.[image]

Toy example:

```
niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E","X","Y")
from <- c("A","A","A","A","B","C","D","E", "X", "B")
to <- c("B","C","D","E","X","X","Y","Y","Y", "C")
temp <- data.table(from=factor(from, levels=niv),
to=factor(to,levels=niv), col=c(rep("blue",5), rep("black",5)))

nodes <-   create_node_df(  n=length(niv), label=niv,  width=0.3) 
edges <- create_edge_df(from = temp$from, to = temp$to, 
rel = "leading_to", label=temp$from, color=temp$col)   
graph <- create_graph(  nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges)
render_graph(graph)
```

It will also be nice to know how to automatically avoid edge labels overlapping with the edges?
At the moment I have to edit the result with Inkscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your questions.

```
library(DiagrammeR)
library(data.table)
niv <- c("A","B","C","D","E","X","Y")
from <- c("A","A","A","A","B","C","D","E", "X", "B")
to <- c("B","C","D","E","X","X","Y","Y","Y", "C")
temp <- data.table(from=factor(from, levels=niv),
to=factor(to,levels=niv), col=c(rep("blue",5), rep("black",5)))

nodes <- create_node_df(n=length(niv), label=niv,  width=0.3)
# Add a vector of colors for fontcolor 
edges <- create_edge_df(from=temp$from, to=temp$to, 
         rel="leading_to", label=temp$from, color=temp$col,
         fontcolor=temp$col) 

graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = edges) 

# Delete the default "layout" graph attribute and
# set direction of graph layout
graphAttr <- get_global_graph_attrs(graph)
graphAttr <- rbind(graphAttr[-1,], 
                   c("rankdir", "LR", "graph"))

graph <- set_global_graph_attrs(graph,
      attr = graphAttr$attr,
      value = graphAttr$value,
      attr_type = graphAttr$attr_type)

render_graph(graph)
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to have each number the same color than the edge, is it possible?

Comment: @skan I updated my answer. I found a solution to your problem with color of edge labels.